# Azure AADconnect attribute filtering using custom attribute created using Schema extension

Tags: active-directory, azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We have a string valued attribute which is attached to user class. This attribute is created using schema extension. When i use this custom attribute to implement a inbound AADconnect attribute filtering (negative) it doesnt work.

However if i am using a extensionattribute to achieve the same filtering it works flawlessly.

Does azure attribute filtering work with customer (extended) attributes ?

Comment: This issue is solved. It was silly mistake from my end. The attribute was not added as an in scope attribute in the AD connector. Once the custom attribute was added in the connector, the filtering works without issue.